# Android, how to pass data from async task called from main activity, to secondary activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

My application has a main activity "A", and a secondary one, "B" (called on a button click).
Just before activity B is started, from activity A I run an async task to get xml data from a remote web service.
How do I then pass xml data to activity B? I can't use something like

```
intent.putExtra("xmlData", xmlData);
```

since, when intent is started, xmlData is empty, yet...

Or, am I using a wrong approach? I decided to run the async task from activity A, instead than B, since I suppose I can save some time waiting for remote data in activity B...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the url, or unique data such as id if the url is the same, to the Activity B from A through intent.putExtra(), and fetch the data with AsyncTask as you onCreate the B activity. A progressDialog in onPreExecute might be in place as well.

Then you can reuse the Activity B if there is any similar task e.g. fetch, parse and present.

Answer (score 0):

Create the intent and fire it off in startActivity inside onPostExecute() after your AsyncTask completes.

Also, is xmlData a String? That's fine, if so, otherwise you need to implement Parcelable. As an aside, you should be careful with your identifiers. A typo or incorrect case in the identifier you pass to putExtra could cause you to not find it.

Comment: I need to startActivity B immediately (to let user see something, even if not up-to-date...), so I can't wait for AsyncTask to complete...